# Mongodb regex embedded search

Tags: regex, mongodb

I got these documents:

- id
- name
- friendList

  - id
  - name

I need to search in php (mongodb) for a friend, so name in friendList. How can I do this?

Comment: friendList is an array of {id, name} objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shell you'd do it like this:

```
> db.people.find({ "friendList.name" : /Joe/})
```

UPDATE: a proof:

```
> db.person.insert({name : 'scatman', friendList : [ {name: 'joe'}, {name: 'nick'}  ]});
> db.person.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f155cafef7b8b0317a8ad17"),
    "name" : "scatman",
    "friendList" : [
        {
            "name" : "joe"
        },
        {
            "name" : "nick"
        }
    ]
}
> db.person.findOne({"friendList.name" : /jo/})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f155cafef7b8b0317a8ad17"),
    "name" : "scatman",
    "friendList" : [
        {
            "name" : "joe"
        },
        {
            "name" : "nick"
        }
    ]
}
>
```

Comment: then either there's a bug in mongodb you're using or there's a bug in your code, or there's no one who's got Joe for his friend :) This query works just fine in mongodb 2.0.1.